# Angular 2 No Provider error after bundling

Tags: angular, gulp, systemjs-builder

I have upgraded my app to use the release version of Angular2 app. It works fine but I run into difficulties when running the app from a bundled file. I use gulp to bundle my app into a single Javascript file which also embeds the templates. I have successfully run a bundled version of my app using Angular2 RC4, however with the release version I get `"No provider for AppConfig"`. AppConfig is one my classes & it's provided by app.module.ts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var basePath = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var del = require("del");

var gulp = require("gulp");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");

var embedTemplates = require("gulp-angular-embed-templates");
var SystemBuilder = require("systemjs-builder");

//Inline templates & transpile into js
gulp.task("js:build", function () {
  return gulp.src("app/**/*.ts", { base: "./app" })
      .pipe(embedTemplates({
        sourceType: "ts",
        basePath: basePath,
        minimize: {
          empty: true,
          quotes: true,
          spare: true
        }
      })) 
      .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
      .js
      .pipe(gulp.dest("build/js"));
});

//Bundle JS files into one file
gulp.task("js:bundle", ["js:build"], function () {
  var builder = new SystemBuilder("build/js", {
    paths: {
      "*": "*.js"
    },
    meta: {
      "@angular/*": {
        build: false
      },
      "rxjs/*": {
        build: false
      }
    }
  });

  return builder.bundle("main", "js/app.bundle.js", { minify: false, mangle: false });
});


gulp.task("js:build:clean", ["js:min"], function () {
  return del([
    "build/js/**/*"
  ]);
});

gulp.task("js:min", ["js:bundle"], function () {
  return gulp.src("js/app.bundle.js")
      .pipe(rename("app.bundle.min.js"))
      .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./js/"));
});

gulp.task("ts:clean", function () {
  return del([
    "./app/**/*.js", "./app/**/*.map", "!./app/ng2-file-upload/**/*"
  ]);
});
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  var defaultExtension = "js";

  var map = {
    "app": "/app",
    "@angular": "node_modules/@angular",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api"
    ,"rxjs": "node_modules/rxjs"
  };

  var packages = {
    "app": { main: "main.js", defaultExtension: defaultExtension },
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": { main: "index.js", defaultExtension: defaultExtension }
    ,"rxjs": { defaultExtension: defaultExtension }, 
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    "common",
    "compiler",
    "core",
    "forms",
    "http",
    "platform-browser",
    "platform-browser-dynamic",
    "router",
    "upgrade",
  ];

  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages["@angular/" + pkgName] = { main: "bundles/" + pkgName + ".umd.min.js", defaultExtension: defaultExtension }; ///bundles/
  }

  var setPackageConfig = packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  var config = {
    bundles: { "/js/app.bundle.min.js?t=@Model.JsFileVersionModifier":  ["main"] },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

**Script from index.html**

```
window["app.config"] = config;

var runApp = function(m) {
    m.RunApplication(config);
}

System.import(toImport).then(runApp, console.error.bind(console));
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

export function RunApplication() {
  const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
  platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```